# Flexbox not working in Chrome or Safari but works in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, flexbox

Flexbox isn't working in Chrome or Safari but works fine in Firefox. The vertical images are expanding to not fit within their container, but in Firefox they're behaving as I want them to. Here is the code, any idea? Thanks.

```css
   body{  max-width: 1970px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0 2%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding-top: 100px;
        }

        a {
          text-decoration: none;
             font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;

           font-size: 1em;
           letter-spacing: -0.03em;
        }

        img {
          max-width: 100%;
        }


        /***********************************
        HEADING
        ************************************/

        header {
          float: left;
          position:fixed;
          top:0;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 99;
          background-color: white;
        }

        h1 {
          font-family: 'Giorgio Sans Web', sans-serif;
          margin: 0 auto;
          font-size:4.5em;
          font-weight: 700;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
        }

        h2 {
          font-family: 'Giorgio Sans Web', sans-serif;
          margin: 0 auto;
          font-size:4em;
          font-weight: 700;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
          line-height: 3em;
        }

        h3 {
          font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
          font-weight: 400;
          font-size:1.3em;
          margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        }

        h4 {
          font-family: 'Giorgio Sans Web', sans-serif;
          margin: 0 auto;
          font-size:2.5em;
          font-weight: 700;
          letter-spacing:0.0625em;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;

        }

        h5 {
          font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
          font-weight: 700;
          font-size: 0.75em;
          line-height: 1.2em;
        }

        p {
           font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
           line-height: 1.5em;
           font-size: 1.2em;
           letter-spacing: -0.03em;
        }

        /***********************************
        NAVIGATION
        ************************************/

        nav {
          /*text-align: center;
          margin: 0 2%;
          box-sizing: border-box;*/
          background-color: white;
        }

        #nav-parent {
          height:;
          display:flex;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -moz-box;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
          padding: 10px 3%;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .nav-icon {
          flex-basis:auto;
        }

        #logo {
         flex-basis:auto;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .contact-button {
         flex-basis:auto;
        }

        nav li a {
          padding:0;
        }

        /***********************************
        SIDE NAV
        ************************************/
        .sidenav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 0;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #F3F3F3;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            transition: 0.5s;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        #sidenav-content {
          margin-left: 13px;
        }

        .sidenav a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .sidenav a h4 {
          overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 16px 8px 0px 6px;
            color: #000;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.1s;
        }

        .sidenav p {
            padding: 0px 8px 8px 26px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #000;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 250px;
        }

        .slide-nav-link {
          margin-top: 10px;
          padding: 8px 8px 8px 26px;
          line-height: 2.2em;
        }

        .slide-nav-social {
          width: 150px;
          height:50px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 26px;
        }

        .slide-nav-social a {
          width:20px;
          padding: 0 15px 0 0;
          display: inline-block;
        }


        .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
            color: #6B00FF;
        }

        .sidenav .closebtn {
            padding: 15px 8px 8px 26px;
            font-size: 30px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }

        .closebtn a:hover {
          color: #000;
        }

        @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
          .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
          .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
        }

        /***********************************
        FOOTER
        ************************************/

        footer {
          font-size: 0.75em;
          text-align: center;
          clear: both;
          padding-top: 50px;
          color: #ccc;
        }

        .social-icon {
          width:20px;
          height: 20px;
          margin: 0 5px;
        }

        /***********************************
        PAGE: PORTFOLIO
        ************************************/

        .gallery{
          margin: 0 auto;
          list-style: none;
          padding-left: 0;
        }

        .gallery figure {
          overflow: hidden;
          float: left;
          width: 48%;
          margin: 1%;
          z-index: 97;
          position: relative;
          float: left;
        }

        .gallery figcaption {
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.97);
          display : flex;
          align-items : center;
          text-align: center;
          color: white;
          float: left;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          opacity: 0;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          height:100%;
          z-index: 98;
          -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
          -moz-transition: all 300ms;
          transition: all 300ms;
          -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
          -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
          transition-delay: 100ms;
        }

        .gallery figcaption h3 { 
          width:100%;
          text-align: center;
          color:#000;
          -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
          -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
          transition: all 300ms ease-out;

        }

        .gallery li:hover figcaption {
          opacity: 1;
        }

        /***********************************
        PAGE: Project
        ************************************/

        .project-gallery{
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0 1.5%;
          list-style: none;
        }

        .project-gallery img{
          max-width: 100%;
          margin: 1.5% 0;
        }

        .project-gallery hr {
          margin: 40px 0;
          border: none;
          height: 3px;
          background-color: #000;
        }

        .project-title {
          max-width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          padding-top: 40px;
        }

        .description-text {
          display:inline;
        }

        .left-column-text {
          width:30%;
          margin-left: 5%;
          margin-top: 8px;
          display:inline-block;
          vertical-align: top;
        }

        .left-column-text p {
            margin: 10px 0 25px 0;
        }

        .left-column-text h5 {
            margin-bottom: -5px;

        }
        .right-column-text {
          width:50%;
          margin: 0 5% 0 8%;
          display:inline-block;
          vertical-align: top;
        }
        .vertical-imgs {
          display: -webkit-flex;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
          display: -moz-flex;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
          display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
          display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
          display:flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          margin: 1% 0;
        }

        .vertical-img-left {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding-right: 3%;
        }

        .vertical-img-right {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .prev-next-buttons {
        margin-right: -3.7%;
        }

        .prev-next-buttons a {
          display: inline-block;
          margin:  0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 20px 5%; 
        }
        .prev-button {
          width:48%;
        }
        .next-button {
          text-align: right;
          width:48%;
        }


        /***********************************
        PAGE: About
        ************************************/

        .profile-photo {
          display: block;
          max-width: 150px;
          margin: 0 auto 30px;
          border-radius: 100%;
        }


        /***********************************
        PAGE: CONTACT
        ************************************/

        .contact-info {
          list-style: none;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          font-size: 0.9em;
        }

        .contact-info a {
          display: block;
          min-height: 20px;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 20px 20px;
          padding: 0 0 0 30px;
          margin: 0 0 10px;
        }

        .contact-info li.mail a {
          background-image: url('../img/mail.png')
        }

        .contact-info li.twitter a {
          background-image: url('../img/twitter.png')
        }

        .contact-info li.phone a {
          background-image: url('../img/phone.png')
        }


        /***********************************
        COLORS
        ************************************/

        /* site body */
        body {
          background-color: #fff;
          color:#000;
        }


        /*green header 
        header {
          background: #6ab47b;
          border-color: #599a68;
        }*/


        /*nav background on mobile
        nav {
          background: #599a68;
        }*/

        /*logo text */
        h1 {
          color: #000;
        }

        /*link color*/
        a {
          color:#000
        }

        /*nav link colors*/
        nav a, nav a:visited {
          color: #000;
        }

        /* selected nav link colors*/
        nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
          color: #5513FE
        }

        /* selected prev next link colors*/
        a h1.selected, a h1:hover {
          color: #5513FE
        }

        a h4.selected, a h4:hover {
          color: #5513FE
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Cari Sekendur - MHG Modern Classic</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/1606-HQIULX.css">
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main1.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
            <meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          </head>


          <body>
            <header>

              <nav>
                <ul id="nav-parent">
                
                    <li class="nav-icon">
                      <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"
                      </span>
                      <img src="img/nav-icon.svg" class="nav-icon">
                    </li>
                
                    <li id="nav-icon">
                      <a href="index.html" id="logo">
                        <h1>CARI</h1>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                 
                    <li class="nav-icon">
                      <a href="mailto:hello@carisekendur.com">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                 
                </ul>
              </nav>

            </header>


        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <div id="sidenav-content">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><img src="img/nav-icon-open.svg" class="nav-icon"></a>
            <div class= "slide-nav-link">
              <a href="index.html">Work</a>
              <a href="about.html">About</a>
              <a href="mailto:hello@carisekendur.com">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div class= "slide-nav-text">
              <a href="index.html" id="logo">
                <h4>CARI SEKENDUR</h4>
              </a>
              <p>Creating visual experiences that make the complex clear and the average exceptional.</p>
            </div>
            <div class= "slide-nav-social">
              <a href='https://workingnotworking.com/carileigh' target="_blank"><img src="img/WNWlogo.svg"></a>
              <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/cskdr/' target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin-black.svg"></a>
              <a href='https://www.pinterest.com/cskdr/' target="_blank"><img src="img/pinterest-black.svg"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.-->
        <script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        }
        </script>


          <div class="wrapper">
            <section class="project-gallery">
              <div class="horiztonal-img">
                <img src="img/mhg-zine/CARI_MHG_ZINE_1.gif" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="project-title">
                <h2>MORGANS HOTEL GROUP - MODERN CLASSIC ZINE</h2>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="description-text">
                <div class="left-column-text">
                  <h5>STUDIO</h5>
                  <p>LMNOP Creative</p>
                  <h5>CREATIVE DIRECTION</h5>
                  <p>Leigh Nelson</p>
                  <h5>DESIGN</h5>
                  <p>Cari Sekendur, Leigh Nelson, Heidi Chisholm</p>
                </div>
                <div class="right-column-text">
                  <p> Morgans Hotel Group launched the global phenomenon of boutique hotels 20 years ago, and to celebrate their rich history they put together a campaign called The Modern Classic. Each of Morgans' properties has a design aesthetic that is unlike anything you've seen before, awe-inspiring and always over-the-top. So, to capture the essence of Morgans' brand, we concepted, designed, and printed a zine for them to distribute to hotel guests. This project was a print designer's dream, complete with gold-holographic foil, gold staples, fluorescent Pantone inks, collage, illustration, a tear-out poster, and even a little pack of temporary tattoos.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="horiztonal-img">
                <img src="img/mhg-zine/CARI_MHG_ZINE_2.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="vertical-imgs">
                <img src="img/mhg-zine/CARI_MHG_ZINE_8.jpg" alt="" class="vertical-img-left">
                <img src="img/mhg-zine/CARI_MHG_ZINE_5.jpg" alt="" class="vertical-img-right">
              </div> 
              <div class="horiztonal-img">
                <img src="img/mhg-zine/CARI_MHG_ZINE_7.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="prev-next-buttons">
                <a href="#" class="prev-button">
                  <h2>PREVIOUS</h2>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="next-button">
                  <h2>NEXT</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <hr class="bottom-hr" style="margin-top: 0px;">

           </section>  

            <footer>
            <p></p>
            </footer>
          </div>  


        </body>


        </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I'm not sure what the answer is from there? Could you point me to it specifically? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your full code so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @michael_B, I updated it. The issue I'm having is only with .vertical-imgs, everything else is working fine

Comment: The images are still missing. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
#nav-parent {

      display:flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      -webkit-flex-flow: initial; 
      flex-flow: initial;       
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 10px 3%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```